# Ruby zlib deflate method is generating invalid characters

Tags: ruby, compression, zlib, deflate

I hope you can help me with this.

I've trying to implement a simple code to deflate a string using the zlib gem in a Sinatra app but it seems to be deflating it wrong?!

Here's my code so far:

```rb
require 'sinatra'
require 'zlib'

get '/v1/generate' do
    file_content = "teste"
    generate_diagram_from file_content
end

def generate_diagram_from file_content
    data_compressed = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(file_content)
end
```

And here's what I'm getting from the deflate method:

```
x�+I-.I�&
```

A weird string with strange characters and everything.

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks you guys in advance!

Comment: A compression generally compress bytes which can't be coerced  into ASCII chars. To share contents as readable strings, try compressing deflate with `Base64.strict_encode64(data_compressed)` and you should get a readable string to copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong is your expectation of a readable string.

Compression produces a sequence of bytes of all values (0..255). This is called binary data. It will always contain "weird" or "strange" characters if you try to display it as you have. In fact, it will almost certainly contain invalid UTF-8 sequences, which is why you are getting the white-on-black question marks. This is why you would never try to display or print such sequences as you have.

If you want to look at them or, for example, put them in a question here, display them in hexadecimal.